# jquery library conflicts issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

links in header looks like..

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> 
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/tmStickUp.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script src="js/validjs.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homestyle.css">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<link href="css/side-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="js/jquery.side-slider.js"></script>
```

if i comment the below jq library..

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

then my stuck-container works on scroll down the page.. but my "username availability checker" plugin does not work.. :(

and... VICE-VERSA...

Please help me to get out of this prob...

Comment: [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: i also used jQuery.noConflict(); but it was not working..

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 libraries for your page weather only 1 library should be use in one website so please use only one library it will work fine.